# How to get all selected rows data in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

there is a problem!! 
In javafx table view i applied multiple selected mode by Shift+mouseClick or Clt+MouseClick. By This

```
tblViewCurrentStore.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                tblViewCurrentStore.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
            }
        });
```

it's ok on GUI but problem is, if i use this code it give me the last selection cell's value,

```
private void btnDeleteOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(tblViewCurrentStore.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getProductName().toString());
    }
```

> Out Put `SAMSUNG HDD`

but when i use this code it give this!

```
private void btnDeleteOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(tblViewCurrentStore.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().toString());
    }
```

It Give me This types of output

```
[List.ListProduct@3a22ea22, List.ListProduct@6d99efa2, List.ListProduct@40fd0f67]
```

But i need when i select multiple row then press delete it will show all selected data like first one.

Hear is my GUI(With multiple selection)
[image]

Comment: Ok, so ... what, then, is the problem you are having?  You've neither asked a question nor stated a problem.

Comment: when i select multiple row then press delete it will show all selected data.
How can i do this?

Comment: I cannot make sense out of your question.  Are you saying that you want to collect an array of selected rows when you click on the delete button?

Comment: yes i need to collect an array of selected rows.

Comment: But you already have `List` of selected rows. You showed the result from calling `toString()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can even use this :**

```
 ArrayList<YourModel> products = new ArrayList<>(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
        for (YourModel model : models) {
            System.out.println(model);
        }
```

**//OR**

```
 final List<YourModel> collect = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. `tblViewCurrentStore.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);`only needs to be set once (thus its a setter). Do it after your `TableView` has been initialized and not on every click.
2. [`SelectionModel#getSelectedItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedItem--) clearly says what it does:

> Returns the currently selected object (which resides in the selected index position). **If there are multiple items selected**, this will return the object contained at the index returned by getSelectedIndex() (which is always the index to the most recently selected item).

3. And finally [`SelectionModel#getSelectedItems`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--) returns all selected objects (as in Java `Object`s).

So if you want the names, you can something like this:

```
List<String> names = tblViewCurrentStore.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().stream()
  .map(ListProduct::getProductName)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```